# Excel-Vba - Double/Date/Time matching and tolerance

Tags: excel, double, vba

My code so far is like this:

```
Sub FindMatchingValue()
    Dim i As Integer, TimeValueToFind As Date
    TimeValueToFind = "04:00:00"
    Sheets("Vessels").Range("F07").ClearContents
    For i = 1 To 25   '
        If CDate(Sheets("Vessels").Cells(i, 1).Value) = TimeValueToFind Then
            MsgBox ("Found value on row " & i)

            Sheets("Vessels").Range("F07").Value = Cells(i, 1).Offset(1, 1).Resize(1).Value
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i
    MsgBox ("Value not found in the range!")
End Sub
```

This code checks Column A for the time inputted in the format xx:xx:xx Both where the input is, and where the times are written are set as "Time" format.
Initially the `CDate` edit was not added. And this caused the code to always return false because, as it had been put, I was trying to "compare apples to oranges".

However adding the `CDate` addition produces a mismatch error. Similarly changing both to be a double also did not work:

```
Sub FindMatchingValue()
    Dim i As Integer, TimeValueToFind As Date
    TimeValueToFind = "04:00:00"
    Sheets("Vessels").Range("F07").ClearContents
    For i = 1 To 25   '
        If Sheets("Vessels").Cells(i, 1).Value = CDbl(TimeValueToFind) Then  ' < This was the line changed
            MsgBox ("Found value on row " & i)

            Sheets("Vessels").Range("F07").Value = Cells(i, 1).Offset(1, 1).Resize(1).Value
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i
    MsgBox ("Value not found in the range!")
End Sub
```

However this one is a different reason, since Excel stores the values as floating points, each value is still different. "It is well known that the expression a==b is likely to return False when a and b are both doubles, even though you might think they are the same. This is due to the finite precision with which floating point numbers are stored."

The way around this would be to Set a tolerance. `If abs(a-b)<tolerance Then`
However i'm not particularly sure which tolerance to use nor how to write it to include without messing up the first loop.
I wonder if anyone could shed some light on this and direct me to which additions I need to make and what sort of tolerances would be acceptable? I think the question is essentially twofold. Thank you in advance!

Comment: hm... the first works for me. When comparing `CDate(sheetvalue) = "04:00:00"` I get true

Comment: Might be worth noting that the `Range` object has a `.Value2` property that doesn't use Date or Currency types so will return a Variant/Double value instead.

Comment: Have you tried using `TimeValue()` instead?

Comment: Right fixed that error, I had a heading and that needed to be omited. Now the problem is that it always returns false for me. Even if 04:00:00 is in the row

Answer (score 1):

Use `TimeValue()` or `TimeSerial()` like so:

```
Sub SO()

Dim x As Date
Dim y As Date
Dim z As Date


x = TimeValue("04:00:00")
y = TimeSerial(4, 0, 0)
z = CDate(Range("A1").value) '// A1 has "04:00:00" entered

Debug.Print x = y '// True
Debug.Print y = z '// True
Debug.Print x = z '// True

End Sub
```

---

Putting this into the context of your code:

```
Sub FindMatchingValue()
    Dim i As Integer, TimeValueToFind As Date
    TimeValueToFind = TimeValue("04:00:00")
    Sheets("Vessels").Range("F07").ClearContents
    For i = 1 To 25   '
        If CDate(Sheets("Vessels").Cells(i, 1).value) = TimeValueToFind Then
            MsgBox ("Found value on row " & i)
            Sheets("Vessels").Range("F07").value = Cells(i, 1).Offset(1, 1).Resize(1).value
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i
    MsgBox ("Value not found in the range!")
End Sub
```

Comment: Still returns false for me, the If statement never runs

Comment: what about if you change it to `CDate(Sheets("Vessels").Cells(i, 1).Value2)` ?

Comment: Same problem, still says "Value not found in the range!"

Comment: I can only assume then that the range holds a different data type, formatted as a time and this is what's causing the issue. If you type `?Sheets("Vessels").Range("A1").Value2` in the immediate window what does it print?

Comment: Method not valid without a suitable object

Comment: If you run the example code I've shown above (the first block, not the 'in context' block) and it works (It works on my machine) then I can only deduce that the issue is in fact with your data or formatting - and not actually a code issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the imprecision of floating point numbers is the cause of your problem.  Remember that the underlying data in a Date data type is still a Double, formatted to look like a date.

The question of "...what sort of tolerances would be acceptable?" is really up to you.  Given that your test value is "hh:mm:ss" then equal to the second may suffice.

There are many ways to achieve this.  If your data is formatted as "hh:mm:ss" then this will work

```
If CDate(Sheets("Vessels").Cells(i,1).Text) = TimeValueToFind Then
```

This relies on the format applied to the sheet being to the same precision as your test value

Comment: Also the value is always by the hour, specifically it's always just 00:00:00, any idea how to write the tolerance in?

Comment: How close do the times have to for _you_ to consider them equal?

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, here is the answer:

```
Sub FindMatchingValue()
    Dim i As Integer, TimeValueToFind As Date, Delta As Double, Tolerance As Double
    TimeValueToFind = Sheets("Vessels").Range("F06")
    Tolerance = 0.001
    Sheets("Vessels").Range("F07").ClearContents
    For i = 2 To 25   '
        Delta = Sheets("Vessels").Cells(i, 1).Value - CDbl(TimeValueToFind)
        If Abs(Delta) <= Tolerance Then

            MsgBox ("Found value on row " & i)

            Sheets("Vessels").Range("F07").Value = Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 1).Resize(1).Value
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i
    MsgBox ("Value not found in the range!")
End Sub
```

So any time in the box F06 typed in, it now finds. A combination of tolerance was used and also converting to a Double. `i = 1-25` was changed to `2-25`, because I had a text header and that was producing a mismatch error.

Comment: How did you arrive at a tolerance of 86.4 seconds?

Comment: Unsure, I got that part of the answer from someone else. It works though. And since mine isn't a secondly thing, the times are rounded up to the hour so the accuracy doesn't need to be perfect. 000.1 is more than enough, infact it's probably too precise but it's good to be sure.